# jqGrid ShowLink Formatter - Custom ID Parameter

Tags: jqgrid

Am I just missing something simple here?  Without going into custom formatting, I'd just like to use my ID values for the ID parameter in the `showlink` formatter.  Here is an example of my sub-grid:

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + '_t';
    $('#' + subgrid_id).html('<table id="' + subgrid_table_id + '" class="scroll" />');
    $('#' + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    colNames: ['Order Number', 'Request Type', 'Owner', 'Order Status', 'Status Date'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'orderid',
        index: 'orderid',
        width: 150,
        key: true,
        formatter: 'showlink',
        formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'AOFOrderFacilities.aspx', idName: 'orderid' }
    }, {
        name: 'type',
        index: 'type',
        width: 100
    }, {
        name: 'owner',
        index: 'owner',
        width: 200
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 150
    }, {
        name: 'date',
        index: 'date',
        width: 150
    }],
    sortname: 'num',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    height: 'auto'
    });
    // TODO: Make this into an AJAX call.  This is just for demo.
    var mysubdata = [
    { orderid: 'O00001234', type: 'Data', owner: 'Melanie Martin', status: 'Saved', date: '2/4/2011 11:48:18 AM' },
    { orderid: 'O00001235', type: 'Voice', owner: 'Billy Solomon', status: 'Submitted to TC', date: '2/4/2011 12:03:47 PM' }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i <= mysubdata.length; i++)
    jQuery('#' + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mysubdata[i]);
}
```

When the links in the first column of the grid are rendered, they correctly display the `orderid` value as the text of the column (the pre-pended "O" is intentional, and should be passed through the system like that), but the resulting links are:

```
http://localhost/somestuff/AOFOrderFacilities.aspx?orderid=1
http://localhost/somestuff/AOFOrderFacilities.aspx?orderid=2
```

And so on, where the ID parameter value is the ordinal index of the grid row rather than the desired value from the data.  Is there an easy way to use the value from the data instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format option `idName` of the formatter `showlink` say only that the name the parameter in the url which you need. The value of the id is **always** the rowid. In your example you use

```
var mysubdata = [
    { orderid: 'O00001234', type: 'Data', owner: 'Melanie Martin',
      status: 'Saved', date: '2/4/2011 11:48:18 AM' },
    { orderid: 'O00001235', type: 'Voice', owner: 'Billy Solomon',
      status: 'Submitted to TC', date: '2/4/2011 12:03:47 PM' }
];
for (var i = 0; i <= mysubdata.length; i++)
    jQuery('#' + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mysubdata[i]);
```

which give as the rowid of the rows the values 1,2, `mysubdata.length`. The setting `key:true` for the column `orderid` will be **ignored** by the method `addRowData`. You can verify in Developer Tools or in Firebug which id has `<tr>` elements of your grid.

I recommend you to modify the above code or just use `data:mysubdata` as a additional parameter of jqGrid instead of the usage more slow old method `addRowData`. Because you defined `key:true` all should work correct. You can also use `localReader:{id:'orderid'}` as additional jqGrid parameter.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even noticed the `data` option, I was just going by some examples on the jqGrid website.  Makes sense that it uses the index from `addRowData` now that you mention it.  Just passing the data array as an option makes much more sense and works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @Oleg: Please help me place a  custom formatter showlink in [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119297/showlink-custom-formatter-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you guys have solved this yet BUT I got it to send across the id of my choice by setting the json reader as follows:

`jsonReader: {
   repeatitems: false,
   id: "[property whose value you want to pass]"
},`

Rich